# Can't get messages using IMAP

Tags: c#, .net, imap

I'm trying to learn how to incorporate IMAP in my code. I did some simple tests with S22.IMAP library but got an error ***(S22.IMAP Bad Server Response Exception)***, It does print `we are connected`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using S22.Imap;
using System.Net.Mail;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ImapClient Client = new ImapClient("1.1.1.1", 143, "XXXXX", "XXXX", AuthMethod.Login, false))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We are connected");
            uint[] uids = Client.Search(SearchCondition.Unseen());
            MailMessage[] messages = Client.GetMessages(uids);
        }
     }
   }
}
```

The exception is at the MailMessage line.

I'm just new to IMAP so please help me with this.

Comment: What kind of server are you connecting to? (Server Software)
Could you provide a Stacktrace? : Add a `try { .. } catch (e)` block with `Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());`

Answer (score 1):

Try use thunderbird for connect. And after successful connection, use  this settings for you connect via s22.

Answer (score 1):

i backed out of this package and start using mimekit/mailkit. I was having issues with this library and there's no more activity. a simple copy paste from the code sample does not even work. check out this library.[MimeKit/Mailkit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit)

and its pretty easy to implement too..the developer is pretty active.thank me later. i found about that coz i was looking for answers about some errors I'm having with s22.imap on github

Answer (score 0):

You're issuing search without having selected a mailbox. That won't do. First open the mailbox you want to search in, then make the Client.Search object.